# /etc/network/interfaces doesn't get loaded automatically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

In Ubuntu 9.10 I configured manually network settings to `/etc/network/interfaces`, and it works fine when I run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Problem is that those settings are not loaded to GUI application (Preferences/Network connections).

I don't want to edit my preferences there, I just want to use my interfaces file as default! Do you know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the auto DEVICENAME and simply write it like this (DHCP):

```
iface DEVICENAME inet dhcp
```

or for a static ip:

```
iface DEVICENAME inet static
address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
netmask XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

If you have written for example `auto eth0` this means, that this interface is configured by the gui.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, I removed the auto eth0 line.